# Every differentiable structure is smoothable to a smooth structure.

Tags: differential-topology

I was studying differentiable manifolds and smooth manifolds. While reading on the Wikipedia website about them, I came across one statement that I have no idea why is it. This statement is

***Every $C^k$-structure is uniquely smoothable to a $C^∞$-structure, i.e., for every $C^k$-structure with $k>0$, there is a unique $C^k$-equivalent $C^∞$-structure.***

I think that this is a beautiful result, because it implies that there is no distinct notion of a $C^k$-manifold ($k>0$, if $k=0$ then not necessarily hold) and a $C^∞$-manifold, which I think will justify the 'interchangeability' of the word 'smooth' and 'differentiable' when we talk about manifold.

Anyone has any idea why this result holds? I also read that it is due to a theorem by Whitney, but I have no idea which theorem is it. If anyone can recommend me some useful material, I will definitely greatly appreciate.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: See Hirsch, "Differential topology", chapter 2. Morally: take your charts. Use convolution to smooth them if the transition maps are $C^k, k < \infty$. Because a slight perturbation of a $C^k$ diffeomorphism is still a $C^k$ diffeomorphism, they will still be diffeomorphisms. The details are not terribly hard to read; I suggest it.